# help with a calculus Integration Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Let $f : [0; 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $$\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx=1$$
Show that there exists $c \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(c) = 3c^2$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For a continuous function $f$ show $\exists c\in (0,1)$ s.t $f(c)=3c^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102162/for-a-continuous-function-f-show-exists-c-in-0-1-s-t-fc-3c2) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(c)%20%3D%203c%5E2%24&p=1)

Comment: I tried a few things, but just had an idea, since the function must go through for the are under the curve to be equal to 1 so I can take that point? not really sure how I would formalize that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function 
$$F(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x f(t)dt − x^3$$ on $[0, 1]$

Then apply Rolle’s theorem.